# Sequence of measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $u_n$ a sequence of measure define on a sigma algebra F such that for every $E \in F$ $u_n(E) \le u_{n+1}(E)$ Prove that the limit is a measure.

I have difficulties to prove countable  addictivity. I have show that the measure of the union is less or equal to the sum of the measure but I'm not able to prove the opposite inequalities. Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: Nothing worse than sequences of misuse.. (You wrote "misuse" instead of "measure" in the title.)

Comment: The problem is how to change the order of the limit of measure and of the limit of the union of set 

Comment: Isn't there some boundedness missing? Otherwise, if you start with some measure $u_0$ and simply define $u_{n+1}(E)=2u_n(E)$ you get a sequence but no limit unless $u_0(E)=0$. But maybe I'm missing something in the definition of the limit?

Comment: @Lovsovs I guess "countable addictivity" could result in a "sequence of misuse"? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need to show is that if $u$ is the limit, then $u(\emptyset) = 0$, and $u$ is countable additive.

The first is easy to see. The second actually follows from a lemma, which I leave you to prove:

> If $a_{mn}$ is a sequence increasing in both $m$ and $n$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\displaystyle\lim_{m\to \infty} a_{mn} = \displaystyle\lim_{m\to \infty}\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}  a_{mn}$, provided at least one of the limits exist.

With this in hand, if $A_i$ is a countable collection of disjoint sets, then 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_n(A_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^m u_n(A_i) \\ = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^m u_n(A_i) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^m u(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty u(A_i) 
$$

You can ask me if you need clarification on the lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea that such a results holds in general. I'd rather try to prove the lemma on my own, but maybe I'll be back asking if I will not able too

Comment: You are welcome!